# Whether to use Task or Parallel class methods

Tags: multithreading, .net-core

I am developing a Asp.Net Core component which has some interface for getting  requests for some process execution.This request would be sync one where the request is accepted and submission token is returned to caller. The requests are added to a queue and processed asynchronously. Each request execution involves making some rest calls for fetching some data , executing process,  etc.

How to process multiple requests from the queue in  parallel whether to use Task or Parallel class

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is a series of I/O bound REST calls. What you should do is loop over those calls, awaiting each. Something like

```
public async Task X()
{
    // add requests to queue
    ...

    foreach (var request in queue)
    {
        await ExecuteRequest(request);
    }
}
```

Parallelism in the classic sense is about threads and CPU bound work, and so isn't suitable for your scenario.